# Largest eigenvalue of the determinantal equation

Tags: eigenvalues, spectral-analysis

I'm reading a paper and it defines $\lambda(\omega)$ as the largest eigenvalue of the determinantal equation:
$$|A'f^{re}(\omega)A-\lambda A'VA|=0$$
Where $f^{re}(\omega)$ is the real part of $f(\omega)$ is the spectral density of stationary time series $X_{t}$ at frequency $\omega$, $V$ is the the variance-covariance of $X_{t}$ and $A=[I_{k-1}|0]'$, where $I_{k-1}$ is the
$(k-1)\times(k-1)$ identity matrix and $0$ is the $(k-1) \times 1$ vector of zeros. What matrix are we calculating its eigenvalues?

From what I know, to extract the eigenvalues $\lambda$s of a matrix $X$ we calculate the roots of $(X-\lambda I)=0$. Where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Presumably $A^\prime V A$ is invertible.  Multiply everything by its inverse: what do you get?

Comment: @whuber the identity matrix?